# How to limit values before decimal and after decimal - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to restrict to enter only numbers in the field and also want to limit the number of characters before decimal and after the decimal.

I have a directive which will restrict to enter only numbers.

```
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/^[^1-9]*|[^0-9]/g, '');
                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

I have a directive which will allow two digits after the decimal and allows n no. of digits before the decimal. But I want to limit characters before the decimal.

```
app.directive('decimalPlaces',function(){
    return {
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('keypress',function(e){
                var newVal=$(this).val()+(e.charCode!==0?String.fromCharCode(e.charCode):'');
                if($(this).val().search(/(.*)\.[0-9][0-9]/)===0 && newVal.length>$(this).val().length){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I want to limit to 6 numbers (i.e., 6 digits) before the decimal.

Comment: Why can't you just use this `[0-9]{6}.[0-9]{2}`

Comment: A small edit to the above. Try this: `/^([0-9]{0,6})\.[0-9]{2}$/`

Comment: Try this may helps you, [ngBehavior](https://github.com/maherAshori/ngBehavior/blob/ngBehavior/README.md)